# Symfony 2 setup, 404 on anything not in "web"

Tags: apache, symfony, apache2, php

I'm trying to setup Symfony 2.  I've downloaded straight from the site and I haven't changed anything.  I can browse to `config.php` and it says `Your configuration looks good to run Symfony.`.  If I go to `app_dev.php`, I get a javascript alert saying that it could not open the web debug toolbar.  It asks me if I want to go to the profiler and if I click okay, I get a 404.  In my apache error log I see that it's saying the file does not exist, thus the 404.

The `.htaccess` in my web folder looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But I don't think the `.htaccess` has anything to do with it since the url is `/app_dev.php/_profiler/50801f9707c71`.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: This is not a dev version.  I'm using 2.1.2 standard from Symfony's download page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a bug in symfony for version 2.1.3 (dev). If you change in your composer.json 2.1.2 (instead of 2.1.*) and then hit "composer.phar update" it should be fine. Similar thing happen few days ago to me.

Comment: I downloaded 2.1.2 standard from symfony.com/download.  It's not a dev release.

Comment: Try dumping assets. app/console assetic:dump or app/console assets:install

Comment: Not sure what that was supposed to do, but it said `Dumping all dev assets.  Debug mode is on.`

Comment: any success? can you tell us what other errors you are getting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18276/discussion-between-troodon-mike-and-tubaguy50035)

Comment: I did get this resolved.  It was a problem with my vhost.  I'm using PHP-FPM and had my proxypassmatch set incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Consider to analize the output of this commands before to continue.

```
php app/check.php
```

You already went to:
localhost/path/to/symfony/app/web/config.php

```
php app/console config:dump-reference framework
```

The .htaccess is exactly the same in 2.1.2 and 2.1.3, and for me fails in both versions. :(

tried

```
php app/console assetic:dump
php app/console assets:install
```

And without success

```
composer update
```

I'll try installing it in another server to avoid any apache missconfiguration

Hope someone could help us.

Comment: app/console assets:install fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

It's all to do with your Apache. Set your Virtual Host as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
    <Directory /var/www/project/web>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

With NGINX conf files, should be something like

```
   location / {
            # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
            try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
            # rewrite all to app.php
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }


    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
             include fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
   }
```

Now it should be gone.

References [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)

Comment: -1 because no where do I mention I'm using NGINX and I've tagged it "apache" and "apache2"

Comment: Fair enough. It doesn't mean it does not solve the issue for Nginx users, tough.